# Selecting value from QListView and on Submit, pass it to Next Window?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qabstractlistmodel

I am using `QListView` to display a simple list of Names from MySQL Database, now I need to send selected value to the Next Window when clicked on **Next >** button, I am new to Qt, saw about `QAbstractListModel` class, but I am not getting which one to use and how, Guide me, thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some pseudo code for you...

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
...
signals:
   void sendListText(const QString&);
private slots:
   void nextClicked(void);

...
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect( ui.nextButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( nextClicked() ) );
}

MainWindow::nextClicked(void)
{
    QModelIndex current = ui.list->currentIndex();
    qDebug() << current.data().toString();
    emit(sendListText(current.data().toString());
}
```

otherwindow.h

```
class OtherWindow
{
    ...
public slots:
    void setEditText(const QString&);

};
```

otherwindow.cpp

```
void OtherWindow::setEditText(const QString& text)
{
    // add your text
}
```

now you have to connect the `MainWindow::sendListText()` to the slot `OtherWindow::setEditText()` where you have access to both of them.

soo long zai

Comment: edited the answer. now you have to fill your new window with it (or maybe another widget).

Comment: right, I got the string in my compilation window, I need to pass it to another window and show it in QTextEdit. So a signal from Next button will have to call QTextEdit's slot ? Similar to that kinda .? guide me thanks..

Comment: edited the answer. oh yeah it would be possible to connect the slot of a gui object direct ... if you have direct access to the ui object, than use its slot, if not make a slot in the class that holds the item.

Comment: sorry being new to this C++, makes me bad to write my own code, am from PHP back ground, have to learn this GUI programming concepts, plz u write down the code, and give some links to learn Qt faster, I have installed Qt, am seeing through those examples, can't figure out much on the implementation..thanks again

Comment: i can't write the whole code for you. you have to look around and find the solutions for yourself, its the best way of learning something :)

for 'learning qt or c++' type `learn qt/c++` into google and you will find plenty of material

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24694/discussion-between-highlander141-and-zaiborg)